# Why are Android SDK tools split into "platform-tools" and "tools" directories?

Tags: android

What decides a tool to go into a particular directory? As an example **adb** was in tools/ but has moved to platform-tools/. Why can't they live in the same directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`platform-tools/` mostly holds binaries that will differ from Windows to OS X to Linux. `tools/` mostly holds JARs and shell script/batch file wrappers for Java-based tools.

As for why the separate directories, I think it is to ease distribution and packaging on the toolsmiths' part.